# Get ID from 1st withTracker query and pass to a 2nd withTracker query? (Meteor / React)

Tags: reactjs, meteor

Im using React with Meteor. Im passing data to my Event React component with withTracker, which gets and ID from the URL:

```
export default withTracker(props => {
  let eventsSub = Meteor.subscribe('events');
  return {
    event: Events.find({ _id: props.match.params.event }).fetch(),
  };
})(Event);
```

This is working but I now need to get data from another collection called Groups. The hard bit is that I need to get an ID from the event that I'm already returning.

The code below works when I hardcode 1. However 1 is actually dynamic and needs to come from a field return from the event query.

```
export default withTracker(props => {
  let eventsSub = Meteor.subscribe('events');
  let groupsSub = Meteor.subscribe('groups');
  return {
    event: Events.find({ _id: props.match.params.event }).fetch(),
    group: Groups.find({ id: 1 }).fetch(),
  };
})(Event);
```

Comment: Does `event` contain the key 'id'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Yasser's answer looks like it should work although it will error when `event` is undefined (for example when the event subscription is still loading).

When you know you're looking for a single document you can use `.findone()` instead of `.find().fetch()`. Also when you're searching by `_id` you can just use that directly as the first parameter. You should also provide `withTracker()` with the `loading` state of any subscriptions:

```
export default withTracker(props => {
  const eventsSub = Meteor.subscribe('events');
  const groupsSub = Meteor.subscribe('groups');
  const loading = !(eventsSub.ready() && groupsSub.ready());
  const event =  Events.findOne(props.match.params.event);
  const group = event ? Groups.findOne(event.id) : undefined;
  return {
    loading,
    event,
    group,
  };
})(Event);
```

There's another issue from a performance pov. Your *two* subscriptions don't have any parameters; they may be returning more documents than you really need causing those subscriptions to load slower. I would pass the `event` parameter to a publication that would then return an array that includes both the event and the group.

```
export default withTracker(props => {
  const oneEventSub = Meteor.subscribe('oneEventAndMatchingGroup',props.match.params.event);
  const loading = !oneEventSub.ready();
  const event =  Events.findOne(props.match.params.event);
  const group = event ? Groups.findOne(event.id) : undefined;
  return {
    loading,
    event,
    group,
  };
})(Event);
```

The `oneEventAndMatchingGroup` publication on the server:

```
Meteor.publish(`oneEventAndMatchingGroup`,function(id){
  check(id,String);
  const e = Events.findOne(id);
  return [ Events.find(id), Groups.find(e.id) ];
});
```

Note that a publication has to return a *cursor* or *array of cursors* hence the use of `.find()` here.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear which field of the `event` object should be supplied to `Groups.find`. But I'll try answering the question.

Try using something like this -

```
export default withTracker(props => {
  let eventsSub = Meteor.subscribe('events');
  let groupsSub = Meteor.subscribe('groups');
  event =  Events.find({ _id: props.match.params.event }).fetch();
  return {
    event,
    group: Groups.find({ id: event['id'] }).fetch(),
  };
})(Event);
```

Note this line -

```
group: Groups.find({ id: event['id'] }).fetch(),
```

can be modified to use whichever field you need.

```
group: Groups.find({ id: event['whichever field'] }).fetch(),
```